# AngularJS: reload module between tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jasmine

I have 2 sub-domains on my site and each uses AngularJS. Each application has name "app" and I use same `spec_helper` to inject dependencies.

If I run tests separately for each domain it works fine, but if I run all together it fails due to `angular.mock.module('app')` doesn't reload `app` module and uses cached version from other application.

So question: how can I clear AngularJS dependency cache between tests?

Here is my helper:

```
#= require angular-mocks
#= require sinon
#= require jasmine-sinon

beforeEach ->
  angular.mock.module('app')


beforeEach inject (_$httpBackend_, _$compile_, $rootScope, $controller, $location, $injector, $timeout) ->
  @scope = $rootScope.$new()
  @http = _$httpBackend_
  ...

afterEach ->
  @http.resetExpectations()
  @http.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()
```

Here is example of regular site spec:

```
#= require site/application
#= require spec_helper

describe 'PlaceCtrl', ->
  beforeEach ->
    @controller('PlaceCtrl', { $scope: @scope })
    ...

  it 'loads place', ->
    expect(@scope.place.id).toEqual(@place.id)
```

Here is example of regular mobile site spec:

```
#= require mobile/application
#= require spec_helper

describe 'PlaceCtrl', ->
  beforeEach ->
    @controller('PlaceCtrl', { $scope: @scope })
    ...

  it 'loads place', ->
    expect(@scope.place.id).toEqual(@place.id)
```